# Need To Count Total Number Of Instances Of Values In A Column And Return The Results In Other Cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, countif

I have a situation where I need to count the total number of instances of values in a column and return the results in other cells.

Users are going to be provided this Excel sheet as a template and will choose from a dropdown list in a specific column.

For example in Column A, the  'Clothing' column, the user would choose any one of these values:

```
Bra
Dress
Pants
Shirt
Shoes
Shorts
Socks
T-Shirt
Thermal Underwear
Underwear
```

And they will have a different number of each item each time.

So ideally I could total up every instance of each term. Then in another column I could return any number above 0, along with the term, like so: 'Bra: 4'. This value would be received later when the file is submitted.

I searched around and tried using the COUNTIF function. I can get this to work generically if I drag it down along side the Clothing column, but the users will submit this themselves, so I need it to do this as automatically as possible.

I made a named range of the terms way out in cell AA in order to make the dropdown, but I couldn't get the function to check the named range, and I'm not sure if I can do that at all.

Can anyone shed some light here? Thanks much and please let me know if more info is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use COUNTIF in a case like this. In the example below I completed a COUNTIF using a named range (Test).

[image]

Hopefully, that provides some help,
Brad

Comment: This worked exactly for what I needed. I was trying to put the named range in the second argument of the COUNTIF and it wasn't working, but now I see why it didn't work. Thanks much.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Subtotal Function 3 for this. Create another A2 row with filter enabled and put a formula similar to =SUBTOTAL(3,A3:A23) . It will count the rows matching your filter.

[image: Here is an example:]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Excel 365, then in **B1** enter:

```
=FILTER(UNIQUE(A:A),UNIQUE(A:A)<>"")
```

and in **C1** enter:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,B1)
```

and copy downward.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use a Pivot Table,

Put the Item in both the Rows and the Values:

[image]